# Symfony - download file from sharepoint using microsoft graph api results in empty file

Tags: php, symfony, microsoft-graph-api

using our symfony app we want to access files from our sharepoint drive.

I succeded downloading the file to my app on localhost using the [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) library and the following code:

controller calls the following function:

```
public function downloadFile(string $driveId, string $itemId, string $file)
{
    $file= $this->fileDir . '/doc/' . uniqid('cloud_', true) . '.docx';
    return $this->getGraph()
        ->createRequest('GET', $this->getUrl($driveId, $itemId) . '/content' . $format)
        ->download($file);
}
```

As I said, on localhost (windows with WSL) everything works fine.
On my symfony test-server (ubuntu), however, the file is created, but is empty (size: 0kb).

Any confiuration or something missing?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your logs? The SDK uses Guzzle under the hood, maybe you can log the response you get back for your request to see if there are any errors when connecting to SharePoint. Both Guzzle 6 & 7 provides a log middleware you could use for that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check the logs. In the meantime I noticed that the response returns with status code 302 (redirect). Do I have to enable something for that (e.g. CORS)?

Comment: @dbrumann I checked the logs with MessageFormatter({error}). There are no errors reported. Status is 302. Response body is empty. This redirection seems to be the issue since I could download a file by using  microsoft.graph.downloadUrl. However, since I want to convert files using PDF I would like to use /content?format?pdf if possible...why does Guzzle not follow redirect on my test server?

Comment: Edit: Tracked it down a bit more. For some reason the 'Location' header is missing in the response on my test-server. Any suggestions which might cause this? Nginx congig or CORS?

Comment: Puh, hard to tell from afar. I'm not familiar with SharePoint administration. It might be configurable there or only apply in certain cases or as you suggest something in your infrastructure like nginx, varnish or anything else handling the traffic is modyfing the headers. I don't think CORS plays into it. In most cases this is handled by the application itself, so I would expect you to at least receive the proper redirect with the Location.